# drf-spectacular swagger authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, basic-authentication, django-class-based-views, drf-spectacular

I'm digging google for 3 hours right now, and can't find solution for my problem. I moved in my project from drf-yasg to drf-spectacular because openapi +3.0 isn't supported in yasg. I want to have an authentication to swagger page. I had a solution like this for yasg:

```
schema_view = get_schema_view(
    openapi.Info(
        title="API",
        default_version="v2",
        description="api description",
        terms_of_service="",
        contact=openapi.Contact(email=""),
        license=openapi.License(name=""),
    ),
    public=True,
    patterns=swagger_urls,
    authentication_classes=(isStaffPermission,),
)
```

The problem is I can't add a similar solution to drf-spectacular. Right now I have this piece of code which ofc doesn't work. My goal is to run a popup for login before swagger page is rendered:

```
class MySchemaView(SpectacularAPIView):
    urlconf=swagger_urls


class CustomSpectacularSwaggerView(SpectacularSwaggerView):
    authentication_classes=(isStaffPermission,)

urlpatterns += [
path("api/v3/schema/", MySchemaView.as_view(api_version="v3"), name="schema"),
path('api/v3/swagger-ui/', CustomSpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(), name='swagger-ui')
]
```

I want to authenticate with my custom class:

```
class isStaffPermission(authentication.BasicAuthentication):
    """Custom authentication class to check if the user is staff."""

    def authenticate(self, request) -> Optional[User]:
        """Authenticate the user"""
        user: Optional[User, bool] = super().authenticate(request)
        if user and user[0] and user[0].is_staff:
            return user
        return None
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?